# Firebase: Query data start at specific value

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I using Firebase to my chat.

I want to get all messages from specific time.
But I only get one message from Firebase.

Here is my code:

```
[[[_conversationDBRef queryOrderedByChild:@"time"] queryStartingAtValue:@(time)] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

        for (FIRDataSnapshot* child in snapshot.children) {
            NSDictionary* msgData = child.value;
            NSLog(@"msgData: %@", msgData);
        }
    }];
```

Query:

```
(lldb) po _conversationDBRef
https://xxxxx-xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/Strike-Fighter/messages/4_5

(lldb) po [[_conversationDBRef queryOrderedByChild:@"time"] queryStartingAtValue:@(time)]
(/Strike-Fighter/messages/4_5 {
    i = time;
    sp = "548914514.2122542";
})
```

Data
[image: Data]

Comment: if you appreciate some advice use integer value instead of floating numbers in you timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving just one value because you are querying using `queryStartingAtValue`. If you wanna receive all the messages of your chats from a date. You will need to use `isGreaterThan`.

So, if you want to retrieve the messages from an specific date you will need to do:

**Firestore**

```
[[[_conversationDBRef queryWhereField:@"time" isGreaterThan:@100000]
    queryOrderedByField:@"time"];
```

**Firebase Realtime Database**

```
 [[[_conversationDBRef queryWhereField:@"time" queryStartingAtValue:@100000]
        queryOrderedByChild:@"time"];
```

You can also limit the number of messages that you want to retrieve(to integrate a lazy loading for example) adding `queryLimitedTo`  to your query.

I think your code is ok. Try to use `queryOrderedByValue`  and give a look to the official documentation in https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data

Anyway, if you application is starting. I suggest you to update your database to Firebase Firestore. It's easier to use, more scalable and looks that Firebase team is going to focus on it more than in realtime.

Comment: Hmm...I can't find the function queryWhereField

Comment: My fault, I confuse it with Firebase Firestore. Im updating my question